# Sending AJAX from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a Chrome Extension that can send AJAX calls with `XMLHttpRequest`. The website that I send the request to it not mine.

When the website gets AJAX call, it check the `Referer` header of the request. If I send the AJAX from my background-page (Chrome Extension) no `Referer` header sends, and the request denied.

How can I change the `Referer` header from the background-page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to intercept your own request with [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) and modify request headers.

Specifically, listen to `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders` in a blocking manner, edit the headers object, and return it to override headers.

Not all headers can be modified in this way, but `Referer` can.

Comment: Can you have give an example of how can I listen to my requests **ONLY**?

Comment: Good question; possibly you can't. But you can do a primary filtering by URL pattern and then only modify Referrer if it's empty.

Comment: `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders` doesn't capture the requests that sends from the Chrome Extension.

Comment: Are your requests synchronous? If yes, then you won't be able to intercept them. You will also need host permissions.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in Xan's answer, you need to use the [webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest). Since I love minimal examples in answers, here is one:

manifest.json permissions need to contain:

```
"permissions": [
    "*://target.site/", 
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
]
```

The js code to modify requests to contain an arbitrary referer:

```
callback = function(details) {
    details.requestHeaders.push({
        name: 'Referer',
        value: 'http://your.arbitrary.referer'
    });
    return {
        requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders
    };
};

filter = { urls: ["*://target.site/target.html"] };
opts = ['blocking', 'requestHeaders']
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(callback, filter, opts);
```

Whenever the browser makes a request to `*://target.site/target.html` now, the referer will be set to `http://your.arbitrary.referer`. This takes effect for requests done by the user (by clicking on links or being on a site that performs AJAX-requests) as well as AJAX-requests by your own extension.

Comment: I don't really understand why it isn't possible for chrome to allow changing the `Referer`-header inside the AJAX-Request. They even could demand an extra permission called `arbitraryReferer`.

Comment: You really made my day!